# Harmonic function on bounded connected space is equal to zero

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I have a question on a proof we did on a lecture in PDE in which we proofed the following:

Let X $\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a open, connected and bounded space and let $f:X \to \mathbb R$ be harmonic and  $f \in C^2 (X) \cap C^1(\overline X)$. 
Assume that $f$ is equal to $0$ on $\partial X \cap B(x_o,r)$ for some $x_0 \in X$ and $r>0$. Then $f=0$.

In the proof we show that the function

\begin{equation}
   F(x) =
   \begin{cases}
     f(x) & x \in B(x_o,r)\cap \overline X \\
    0  & x \in B(x_o,r) \setminus X
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
is harmonic itself and thus $f=0$ but I am not entirely sure why this is sufficient. 
I thought one would assume that there is some $x \in B(x_o,r)\cap \overline X$ such that $F(x)\neq 0$ then it is not constant and therefore it must have its maximum on the Boundary but i don't see why that would be a false statement.

Comment: Is $X$ open in $\mathbb R^n?$

Comment: yes it is, i changed the question

Comment: $\partial X \cap B(x_o,r)$  could be empty.

Comment: Have you already shown that harmonic functions are real analytic? This is why $f=0$ on a ball is sufficient to show $f=0$ on that connected component.